# Trying to do scheduled message with cron but getting 'send' of undefined error

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to do a scheduled message with cron on Discord.js v12. but i am getting this error:

> channel.send("test");
> ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

My codes are this:

```
const cron = require('cron');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

const channel = client.channels.cache.get('channelidhere');
const job = new cron.CronJob('0 0 12 * * *', () => {
  channel.send("test");
});

job.start();

client.login("token")
```

Comment: Move your code in the ready event of the client. That should fix the issue.

Comment: Either your channel ID is wrong, or you're trying to get a channel before it's been cached. As @Jakye pointed out, you should put this in your client's `ready` event so it will only fire when everything is cached and... well, ready.

Comment: I did it error is gone, but bot is completely silent now tried change channel.send to console.log still silent.

Comment: what do you mean with silent?

Comment: I meant ready event is not working, command does not work when i put ready event on it

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```js
 const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(
    (channel) => channel.id === "ChannelIdHere"
  );
```